# How to get a alert message on click of a element in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new angularJs, trying to do some dom modifications on click of a button/element. To begin with i just wanted to know how can i get the output in the below fiddle link through angular. can anyone please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpaq52oo/

```
$("#clickMe").on("click",function()
{
 alert("hi there");     
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where's your angular code????

Comment: i want to learn Angular, can you please help me angular equivalent code for the above ?

Comment: If you want to learn angular take a look a this free course http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js. Here is not the place to learn.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/851/

Comment: hi guys .. i am going crazy.. pulling my hairs out to learn dom manupilation in angular. i have built something in jsfiddle, can anyone help me to get this done in angular ? jsfiddle.net/jz006a77

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-click="clickMe()">Click here and see what happens</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe= function(){
         alert("hi there");  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">   
<button ng-click="alertme()">click me</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[])
  .controller('myctrl',function($scope){
     $scope.alertme = function(){
        alert('hi there');
  }
  });
```

Comment: hi guys .. i am going crazy.. pulling my hairs out to learn dom manupilation in angular. i have built something in jsfiddle, can anyone help me to get this done in angular  ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jz006a77/